# Cloud Firestore - request variable not working as expected

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple firestore database with few countries, and a city in each country. Consider each country a document i.e. france. while reading document using request variable facing PERMISSION_DENIED exception for following 2 scenarios.

Sharing following things for your reference 
1) FireStore configuration 
2) Specific configuration which is not working
3) relevant logs for each failure 
3) class file to create and read firestore database 
4) methods to call following scenarios

**Scenario 1 - at least one of following 2 permission should work, but neither of them is working**

```
allow read : if request.resource.__name__ != null ; 
allow read : if request.resource.__name__ == null ;
```

**Error Log**

I/System.out: firestoreTest ACTION_READ onFailureListener e = com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
I/System.out: firestoreTest getOnCompleteListener  Unsuccessful

---

**Scenario 2 - Though document name 'france' exists in database, its not working.**

```
allow read : if request.resource.__name__ == /databases/$(database)/documents/Countries/france ;
```

**Error Log**

I/System.out: FireStoreTest.firestoreTest action = [2], country = [france], hashmapCountry = [null]
I/System.out: firestoreTest ACTION_READ onFailureListener e = com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
I/System.out: firestoreTest getOnCompleteListener  Unsuccessful

---

**Scenario 3 -  No issue, and working well. Only presented because similar scenario 2 is not working**

```
 allow read : if resource.__name__ == /databases/$(database)/documents/Countries/france ;
```

**Error Log**

I/System.out: FireStoreTest.firestoreTest action = [2], country = [france], hashmapCountry = [null]
I/System.out: firestoreTest getOnCompleteListener  Successful  {city=paris}

---

**Basic Configuration to test scenarios**

```
service cloud.firestore {
     match /databases/{database}/documents
    {
        match /Countries/{country}
          {

        allow write : if true ;     
        allow read : // replace as per below scenario 

          }    
    }    
}
```

}

---

**Method to create collection, need to be called only once before testing**

```
HashMap<String, String > hashMap = new HashMap<>() ;
hashMap.put("city","paris") ;
fireStoreTest.firestoreTest(fireStoreTest.ACTION_ADD,"france",hashMap);
```

---

**method can be used to test all following 3 scenario**

```
 fireStoreTest.firestoreTest(fireStoreTest.ACTION_READ,"france",null);
```

---

**Below class is used to test all above 3 scenarios**

```
package com.firestoreTest ;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class FireStoreTest {

public static final int ACTION_ADD = 1 ;
public static final int ACTION_READ = 2 ;
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore ;

public FireStoreTest() {
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() ;
}

public void firestoreTest(int action, String country, HashMap hashmapCountry)

{
    System.out.println("FireStoreTest.firestoreTest action = [" + action + "], country = [" + country + "], hashmapCountry = [" + hashmapCountry + "]");

    DocumentReference documentReference =  firebaseFirestore.collection("Countries").document(country) ;

    switch (action)
    {
        case ACTION_ADD:



            documentReference.set(hashmapCountry)
                    .addOnFailureListener(e-> System.out.println("firestoreTest ACTION_ADD onFailureListener e = "+e)  )
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            System.out.println("firestoreTest setOnCompleteListener  Successful  " );
                        } else
                        {
                            System.out.println("firestoreTest setOnCompleteListener  Unsuccessful  " +task.getException() );
                        }

                    }) ;





            break ;

        case ACTION_READ:

            documentReference.get()
                    .addOnFailureListener(e-> System.out.println("firestoreTest ACTION_READ onFailureListener e = "+e))
                    .addOnCompleteListener(taskDocumentSnapshot->{

                        if (taskDocumentSnapshot.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = taskDocumentSnapshot.getResult() ;

                            if (documentSnapshot.exists())
                            {
                                Map mapDocumentSnapshot = documentSnapshot.getData() ;

                                System.out.println("firestoreTest getOnCompleteListener  Successful  "+mapDocumentSnapshot );

                            } else
                            {
                                System.out.println("firestoreTest getOnCompleteListener  no data found  " );
                            }

                        } else
                        {

                            System.out.println("firestoreTest getOnCompleteListener  Unsuccessful  " );
                        }

                    }) ;
            break ;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Received below response from firebase support

the issue lies in the use of request.resource. As stated in [our documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#resource), request.resource (and all of its variables like request.resource.**name** and request.resource.data.city) is used in write operations, but not read operations.